# ASP Session value

Tags: asp-classic

I'm setting a Session of MM_CustomerID in my code and then further down the page I need to insert the value of that session into a table. But each time I try to do this it comes up with an Invalid column name 'varCustomerID'.

At the top of the page I have this code;

```
<% 
set rscustomerid = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rscustomerid.ActiveConnection = CmdAddCustomer.ActiveConnection
rscustomerid.Source = "SELECT @@IDENTITY as MaxCustomersID  FROM Customers"
rscustomerid.CursorLocation = 2
rscustomerid.LockType = 3
rscustomerid.Open()
Session("MM_CustomerID")=rscustomerid("MaxCustomersID")
Session("MM_UserAuthorization") = "5"
%>
```

Then further down, i'm trying to set a variable of varCustomerID to be equal to the MM_CustomerID session;

```
<%
varCustomerID = Session("MM_CustomerID")
%>
```

And then try inserting the value of that variable varCustomerID into the Orders table as follows;

```
<% 
'Insert record into Orders recordset when form is submitted
'and store the unique OrderID
'Version Date: 09 August 2009
set CmdAddOrder = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
CmdAddOrder.ActiveConnection = MM_dbconn_STRING
CmdAddOrder.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Orders (OrderCustomer,OrderGrandTotal,OrderStatus) VALUES (varCustomerID,0.00,3)"
CmdAddOrder.CommandType = 1
CmdAddOrder.CommandTimeout = 0
CmdAddOrder.Prepared = true
CmdAddOrder.Execute()
%>
```

I wondered if anyone might be able to help? Perhaps there's an easier way of just inserting the session value into the table, instead of creating a variable for it?

Thanks.

Comment: use a Store procedure for the task... it will take care of SQL Injections for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast varCustomerID to a string for the query. Slight change to Paul's answer should get you working but like he says you need to be careful of injection attacks.

```
"INSERT INTO Orders (OrderCustomer,OrderGrandTotal,OrderStatus) VALUES (" & varCustomerID & ",0.00,3)"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the sql command text to:

"INSERT INTO Orders (OrderCustomer,OrderGrandTotal,OrderStatus) VALUES (" + varCustomerID + ",0.00,3)"

However you could be vulnerable to SQL injection... really you should parametrise this query:

http://aspnet101.com/aspnet101/tutorials.aspx?id=1

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'm now getting the following error;

Type mismatch

Comment: You should probably debug and step through the code. Check what value you are getting on the line:

varCustomerID = Session("MM_CustomerID")


You may need to cast it to an int something like

varCustomerID = Cint(Session("MM_CustomerID"))

Comment: I ran a Response.Write to check that it is grabbing the CustomerID and it returned the correct value.

Looks like it's just having an issue trying to put the number into the OrderCustomer column (which has as Data Type of int);

Type mismatch: '[string: "INSERT INTO Orders ("]'

Comment: Have you tried passing in Cint(varCustomerID) instead of just varCustomerID?

This casts the string to an integer

Comment: Heya. Just tried that actually, but still writes the same error.

Comment: Ok, you definitely don't have extra speech marks in your commandtext do you 

"INSERT INTO Orders (OrderCustomer,OrderGrandTotal,OrderStatus) VALUES ('" + varCustomerID + "',0.00,3)"


instead of


"INSERT INTO Orders (OrderCustomer,OrderGrandTotal,OrderStatus) VALUES (" + varCustomerID + ",0.00,3)"

(see those extra single speech marks in the first one arround varCustomerID)

Comment: Heya, yes - here's the code I now have;

<%
varCustomerID = Cint(Session("MM_CustomerID"))
%>

<% 
CmdAddOrder.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Orders (OrderCustomer,OrderGrandTotal,OrderStatus) VALUES ('" + varCustomerID + "',0.00,3)"
%>

Comment: Don't know if it would be beneficial to see the full code page?
http://gist.github.com/165141

Comment: Hey Paul. Found out the problem, had to replace the + with & as follows; VALUES (" & varCustomerID & ",0.00,3)"

Comment: Ahh, nice one. Good luck with the rest of the product fella